# DigiSpark USB issue

Tags: arduino-ide, usb, installation, digispark

I installed the drivers for x64 and got this:

[image: Device driver install]

Notice it did not install the first one - USBSER.

However, I am able to upload code in the Arduino IDE so I went ahead and uploaded the CDC ECHO sketch and all went well there.

But Windows does not see it as a VCP:

[image: Devices]

[image: Device properties]

[image: Driver file]

[image: Select device driver]

[image: Windows encountered a problem]

What can I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Use this bootloader:

https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus

Make sure you have Arduino IDE 1.6.5+

Open the IDE, go to

> File > Preference

then find "Additional Boards" URL. Then paste [this link](http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json) and then click OK.

Then go to

> Tools > Boards > Boards Manager

and change the type to "Contributed" then install the "Digistump AVR Boards". Then change the Arduino board to the Digispark that you have and you're ready to go!

Comment: done all of that. if my posted images would work then it would be better understood.

Comment: sry i couldn't help :(